# C# - How to overload [][] (two square brakets)

Tags: c#, properties, operators, overloading

I want to create my `Matrix class` with field: `double[][] _elements`,
but I don't know how to write property `[][]` for `get` and `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an indexed property that looks like that you'd need to do

```
public class YourClass
{
    private double[][] _elements;

    public double[] this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _elements[index];
        }
        set
        {
            _elements[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

That would allow something like

```
var instance = new YourClass();
var d = instance[0][1];
instance[0][1] = 2.5;
```

Though at this point you'd need to be vary careful about your index ranges and should probably expose `_element.Length` in another property.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `Indexer` you need :

```
public double this[int x, int y]
{
    get { return _elements[x][y]; }
    set { _elements[x][y] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

```
public double[] this[int i]
{
    get { return arr [i]; }
    set { arr [i] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Based on the OP's `_elements` it seems that the property should be of type `double[]`.

Comment: Assuming that `arr` is `double[][]` the return type should be `double[]` not `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an indexer with two arguments?

```
public double this[int i, int j]
{
    get
    {
        return _elements[i][j];
    }
    set
    {
        _elements[i][j] = value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myValue = myInstance[1, 4];
```